# define variable index

Tags: summation, index

im in the medal of coding and i reached the point where i have something like this, 
[image]

the problem is i have up to 35 terms and all should be index in order to preform summation to count all possibilities, is there any automatic way to generate as variable index as much as i want ? also is there any way to fill all the summations automatically ?

thanks

Comment: Are you looking for `Table[Subscript[u, Unique["x"]], 35]`, or maybe `Array[Subscript[u, x[#]] &, 35]`? (`Subscript` could be replaced by `Indexed`.)

Comment: actually i want 35 term of u[x] with variable index, so i can do summation. in the pic its only 3 terms i need 32 term extra each term will have summation with same index letters

Comment: Yes, I should have written it this way: `Table[Subscript[u, Unique["x"]][t], 35]`, and `Array[Subscript[u, x[#]][t] &, 35]`. For instance for the latter, the sum iterators are the `x[1]`, ..., `x[35]`.

Comment: the table command did not work, what about the summation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use $ii[1]$, $ii[2]$, $ii[3]$ etc instead of $ii$, $kk$, $ll$:

```
expr = Product[Indexed[u, ii[i]][t], {i, 3}];

Sum[expr, ##] & @@ Array[{ii[#], jj} &, 3]
```

[image]

Comment: what about making it start from 1?
this will generate the terms what about making it start from 1?

Comment: @LoveEva, it implicitly starts from 1 but if you want it explicit use `{ii[#], 1, jj}` in the Array

Comment: final thing, im using mathematica 7 and this command is only available in advanced versions of the program is there any alternative way in 7?

Comment: @LoveEva, you can use `Subscript` instead of `Indexed`. Or just make the index an argument of u, as in `u[ii[3], t]`

Answer (score 1):

If you really have that simple structure, exploit it:

```
Clear[u]
jj = 4;
Times @@ (Total /@ Array[u, {3, jj}])
```